# Cutsets and disjoint edge sets in graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph

If $H=(V,E)$ is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) then we say that $C\subseteq V$ is a *cutset* if $C\cap e \neq \emptyset$ for all $e\in E$. We set
$$\text{cut}(H) = \min\{|C|: C \text{ is a cutset of }H\}.$$ A subset $D\subseteq E$ is said to be a *disjoint* if the members of $M$ are mutually disjoint. Set $$\text{disj}(H) = \sup\{|D|: D\subseteq E\text{ is disjoint}\}.$$ An easy argument shows that $\text{disj}(H) \leq \text{cut}(H)$ for any hypergraph $H$.

**Question.** If $G = (V,E)$ is a simple, undirected graph with $\text{cut}(G) = \text{disj}(G)$, is there necessarily a disjoint set $D_0\subseteq E$ and a (minimal) cutset $C_0$ such that $|C_0\cap d| = 1$ for all $d \in D_0$?

Comment: take any maximal disjoint set and any minimal cutset, an easy argument which you mentioned shows that this works

Comment: The minimal cutset might intersect the maximal disjoint set in more than $1$ point depending on how the other edges are situated... or am I wrong?

Comment: it must intersect each edge in this disjoint family at least once, but it has as many elements as we have disjoint sets

Comment: @FedorPetrov You are assuming that the graph is finite, which was not stated. On the other hand, if infinite graphs are allowed, then any infinite complete graph is a trivial counterexample.